# Битмап из ресурсов и кисть

Tags: c++, winapi

Хочу закрасить окно узором битмапа, который грузится из ресурсов и помещается в кисть. Не могу понять какие лучше функции использовать и с чего начать.

Comment: Приведите ваш код, как вы создаете окно. Вы устанавливаете ему цвет фона?

Comment: Начните с загрузки битмапа из ресурсов.

Comment: WinAPI CreateBrushIndirect SetBrush

Comment: Кисть создавайте с помощью `CreatePatternBrush()`. Эта функция спокойно принимает полноцветные изображения, возвращаемая кисть представляет собой замощение копиями изображения в масштабе 1:1 к исходному.